Sobre el uso de ‘cotillón’ en general
Básicamente, en el DLe aparece lo que supongo que es la acepción originaria, que hace referencia a una especie de danza. Hoy en día, en la Argentina el término se usa para:

Referirse a un negocio en donde se venden insumos para fiestas infantiles: globos, piñatas, velitas, pulseras, guirnaldas, serpentina, e incluso las golosinas que se ponen en las sorpresitas.
Referirse a cualquier cosa que pertenezca a tal rubro: artículos de cotillón.

En el Damer aparece algo relacionado con lo que me interesa traer a esta pregunta; aunque lo marcan como que sólo se usa en Perú, cuando también se usa acá. Lo que quiero saber entonces es:

Si en los demás países también se usa este mismo término para referirse a esta especie de negocios.
Sino, si usan otro término específico o simplemente cómo le dirían (‘tienda de artículos para fiestas?’).

Saludos.

En Guatemala eso sería una piñatería, dónde suelen vender todo lo necesario para una fiesta infantil. También un servifiestas, aunque es menos común su uso.

Primeramente depende del país. Por ejemplo según Wikipedia cotillón es un tipo de baile proveniente de Francia inventado alrededor de 1700 para ser bailado por parejas de a cuatro formando un especie de cuadrado.
En España un cotilla es una persona chismosa, metiche, y por extensión un cotillón es alguien más chismoso/a. Nunca he escuchado, visto o leído que lo usen refiriéndose a un lugar.
Como respuesta a tu pregunta puedo responder en dos regiones, una es Centroamérica donde como dice @jachguate se le diría piñatería, una tienda donde se venden todo tipo de cosas para fiestas. Me atrevería a decir que en México también le dirían así, pero tengo mis reservas.
En España como tal les dicen tienda de artículos para fiestas aunque con el auge de la población china, hoy por hoy todo tipo de estas tiendas o bazares se están convirtiendo en "Chinos", que es un termino utilizado a una tienda administrada por ciudadanos Chinos.

Sí, y en Wikipedia también dice que: Actualmente se suele denominar cotillón a las fiestas con música y baile que tienen lugar en fechas festivas..., es decir a las fiestas en general. Me basta con que me digas que en España no tienen ningún nombre particular que sea equivalente. Todo suma.

Abundando un poco en el uso de la palabra cotillón en España, decir que actualmente su significado se ha reducido y únicamente se usa para la fiesta de fin de año. Aunque las bolsas que contienen diversos elementos "festivos", léase sombreritos cónicos de cartón, confetti, silbatos de plásticos, globos, antifaces de cartón ... que pueden emplearse en cumpleaños se siguen llamando bolsas de cotillón.
Quedan pocas tiendas especializadas en ese tipo de artículos. Como indica Ochoa actualmente suele haber una sección dedicada a ellos en cualquier "chino".
Como curiosidad indicar que una búsqueda en Google de "tiendas de cotillón cerca de mí" localiza las escasas tiendas de artículos de fiesta y pirotecnia que quedan en mi ciudad; lo cual indica que el motor de búsqueda tiene identificados como sinónimos ambos términos y que el primero de ellos está en uso.

